# having vim moving <{> <}> to skip folds

Tags: vim

I would like the paragraph maps `{` `}` to behave like `zj` , `zk`, i.e. keeping folds closed when they meet one. Is there a way to get this behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the fact that inside a mapping, Vim doesn't automatically open folds. Therefore, it's enough to map the commands to themselves:

```
:nnoremap } }
:nnoremap { {
```

Alternatively, if you want this behavior for *all* such motions, you can

```
:set foldopen-=block
```

See `:help 'foldopen'`.